# Throwing Exception from from ANTLR4 visitor

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am an ANTLR newbie. Here is a grammar for which I am trying to write a Visitor class.

```
grammar extremelysimpleexpr ;

stat : expr ;
expr : sub ;
sub : add ( '-' add )* ;
add : VAL ( '+' VAL )* 
    | VAL
    ;  


VAL : [0-9]+ ;
[ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;
```

Vistor.java

```
 .........
  public Integer vistAdd(ctx) {
       if (some cond) {
          throw new Exception()
       }
  }
 ..........
```

The problem is I am not able to throw exception since the generated code does not handle exceptions, the method signature does not have `throws exception` in its signature. Is there any way out of it ?

Answer (score 0):

An unchecked exception would work, as suggested by Sam Harwell - as one of two options - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618586/checked-exceptions-in-visitors). I just tried it.

You can catch that exception wherever you want.